# Entity Framework 4 - Repository Pattern - How to avoid full load of entity with nested relation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, entity-framework-4, repository, dto

I'm currently working with **Entity Framework 4** and the **repository Pattern** in **c#**.

I have an entity (`Category`) which contains a property (`Main Category`) which refers to the Main Category and some other stuff.

Because of navigation property, the main category has access to their childs category.

For reasons I'll explain later, *I disabled lazy loading.*

When I try to get a category with his id and because of navigation properties, EF4 load the whole graph whereas I just want to load the *targeted category* and *not* the related (parent or child) entity.

I want to do this because this entity is aimed to be converted into a dto and used in a WCF WebService. The full load of graph is not compatible with my approach.

Is there a way to avoid loading of nested entity with EF4? If not, can NHibernate be made to work that way? (I was thinking that disabling lazy loading will allow me to have full control on what I want to load (explicit or eager loading) but it seems not ...)

Comment: Why don't you just do lazy loading, and use EF4 to eager load the properties when forming your queries as needed?

Comment: I'm using AutoMapper to convert POCO from repository to DTO. If I use lazy loading, AutoMapper will load the full graph of database when he'll convert the navigation properties.

Comment: EF will not load related entities if you don't request them. Show your code.

Comment: Right but if your repository classes can't handle requests to eager load when needed, you are going to end up with optimization issues down the road.  It might be a good idea to look at your repository methods and see if there is some way to add parameters (or some kind of call) that allows you to eager load child records when specified.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : As I say in in the same time you wrote your comment, the problem is caused by AutoMapper which force full load of graph by trying to convert POCO to DTO through Navigation Properties. I will post my code ASAP.

Comment: @KallDrexx : Before I decided to use repository pattern, I was using direct LINQ method to interact with the DataContext. Even like this, I was not able to specify exactly which related entity I wanted to load. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: With Linq you have to specify `query.Include(x => x.EagerLoadProperty)`.  In regards to auto-mapper, you might be able to get around that issue by telling auto-mapper to ignore the properties that are other DB entities.

Comment: @KallDrexx : I try to use query.Include(x => x.EagerLoadProperty), but even if it works in several case, I can't succeed with with my(Category-MainCategory) relationship. Indeed, when I load the Category, EF4 load also the MainCategoryProperty (whereas I disabled LazyLoading), and so load also , the child categories of the MainCategory. I don't understand why it load the MainCategory.

Comment: First of all, as far as I am aware, if you disable lazy load then the `Category.MainCategory` property should be `null`, it shouldn't be eager loaded by default.  I would post your code for disabling lazy loading so we can see if it was done correctly.

Comment: Okay, I will do this as soon as I can. I haven't access to it right now.

Comment: I rechecked my code in debug, and indeed, the `Category.MainCategory` was null, but, the navigationProperty : `Category.ChildCategory` was set with a collection of 3 category.

I check my code, and I can confirm that I disabled the lazy loading in the EF4 EDMX properties and in the UnitOfWork (related to the repository) used with the loading of the category.

I wanted to post my code, but because the code in distributed in many layer, it would be difficult to past all the related methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you project your entity object into that dto object when you get the results from the object context itself? You can use something like

```
myclient.Select(c => new clientdto(){ name = c.name, email = c.email, phone = c.phone})
```

which will return the `Ienumerable` of the `clientDTO` object.