# Avoid loading related entities EF5

Tags: entity-framework

I am loading a set of entities from DbContext using EF5 but each entity is linked to multiple tables and makes it load related entities everytime. Is there anyway that I can turn that off, and not manually project into a new object like

[Entity Framework 4 - Repository Pattern - How to avoid full load of entity with nested relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405697/entity-framework-4-repository-pattern-how-to-avoid-full-load-of-entity-with)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Executive Summary:

```
 Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

See [Enter Framework Loading options explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)